# Flexible alternatives for locking (selective lock)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I need to resolve situation for equal objects with different memory location (it happens for REST request because of multithreading).

So as part solution I have implemented service. I'm sharing here most important parts:

```
private Map<T, ReentrantLock> lockHolder = new HashMap();

void unLock(T monitorMarker) {
    synchronized (lockHolder) {
        ReentrantLock lock = lockHolder.get(monitorMarker);
        if (lock == null || lock.getHoldCount() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        lock.unlock();
        if (lock.getHoldCount() == 0) {
            lockHolder.remove(monitorMarker);
        }
    }
}

ReentrantLock getLockForCalendar(T monitorMarker) {
    synchronized(monitorMarker) {
        ReentrantLock lock = lockHolder.get(monitorMarker);
        if (lock == null) {
            lock = new ReentrantLock();
            lockHolder.put(monitorMarker, lock);
        }
        return lock;
    }
}
```

in general it works without problems.

Right now I need to map this util on domain metadata (solution could be using `Map<String, Map<Object, Lock>>` or cache injecting and nothing unresolvable)...

I prefer to use JDK util or open source util with similar solution because they already provide handling this cases... I believe a lot of developers faced with similar issues and solution should be present in open source libraries. I've researched `spring` utilities, `apache` utilities some `google` libraries but I haven't found satisfactory result.

Suggest me consider right library(s) to use please.

Comment: Re, "I need to resolve situation for equal objects with different memory location." Why? Have you determined the actual cost of occasionally using the same lock object for two different-but-equal data objects? And, have you determined that the cost is too much for your application to bear?

Comment: @jameslarge. That makes application stress stable. QA provided cases where my REST receives at same time two different patch requests for different entities with same basement. I know I should handle it with optimistic locking, but situation doesn't allow me to add model changes (i wrote earlier same entity basement but different custom entity part). So I think workaround with synchronization most suitable for now, but I hope i'll handle it after production :) .

Comment: Do you mean you want different locks for `a` and `b` where `a.equals(b)`  but `a != b`? Or do you want the same lock?

Comment: @Kayaman it should be same lock for case `a.equals(b)` and `a != b`

Comment: Wait, what data are protected by these locks? is it the `a` and `b` objects themselves? But if those objects need protection, then that implies that they are mutable.  Does mutating the objects change the equality relationship? (HashMap with mutable keys generally is a Bad Thing!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guava's [Striped lock](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) implementation does what you're doing, but properly (and with far more options regarding weak locks, laziness, semaphores instead of locks etc.).

It's not that different from what you've done, but you've combined `synchronized` with locks, whereas a `ConcurrentHashMap` can get rid of the explicit synchronization (and provide some performance benefits by not locking the whole map every time it's accessed).